# Please explain how .NET works, using classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I run the following code snippet.

```
Public Shared Sub DisplayDnsConfiguration() 
Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
For Each adapter In  adapters
    Dim properties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
    Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description)
    Console.WriteLine("  DNS suffix................................. :{0}", properties.DnsSuffix)
    Console.WriteLine("  DNS enabled ............................. : {0}", properties.IsDnsEnabled)
    Console.WriteLine("  Dynamically configured DNS .............. : {0}", properties.IsDynamicDnsEnabled)
Next adapter

End Sub 'DisplayDnsConfiguration
```

I understand the end result, some properties are printed. However I don't understand the way there.

The following three lines are the ones I don't understand:

```
1. Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
2. Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
3. For Each adapter In  adapters
```

Regarding line 1, why is the As NetworkInterface(), I understand when it is string or integer etc.. but not NetworkInterface(). Then I assume it populate the "adapters" with the data returned from the GetAllNetworkInterfaces() method.

Regarding 2. Same as above, but why doesn't it use () in the end?

Regarding 3. Why use the adapter In adapters? What does it actually do? I understand it loops through the interfaces, but how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim yourIndividualName as SomeType
```

declares a variable called `yourIndividualName` which type is `SomeType`. `int` and `String` are rather primitive types compared to a `NetworkInterface`, but declaring them is the same.

For example:

```
Dim someText as String
```

To declare an array (a list) simply add `()` to the type

```
Dim severalTexts as String()
```

Back to your question:

1:

```
Dim adapters As NetworkInterface()
```

Declares a list (actually an array) of `NetworkInterface` called `adapters`, but the list is empty. Then `= NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` fills that list.

2:

```
Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
```

This declares one empty variable of type `NetworkInterface`. It is later used to go through the list.

3:

```
For Each adapter In adapters
    ' do some stuff
Next adapter
```

This takes the first element in the list `adapters`, saves it in `adapter` and does the stuff between `For` and `Next`. When there is another item in the list, `For` takes the next one, saves it in `adapter` and so on, until it reached the end of the list `adapters`. Between `For` and `Next` you can use `adapter` to e.g. display some of its properties etc.

A shorter version that does the same:

```
For Each adapter as NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    Dim properties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
    Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description)
    Console.WriteLine("  DNS suffix................................. :{0}", properties.DnsSuffix)
    Console.WriteLine("  DNS enabled ............................. : {0}", properties.IsDnsEnabled)
    Console.WriteLine("  Dynamically configured DNS .............. : {0}", properties.IsDynamicDnsEnabled)
Next adapter
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on the type NetworkInterface.. I understand the types string, integer etc.. but what is the NetworkInterface type? Where is it defined?

Comment: Simply right click on it select 'Go to definition' and see for yourself. Visual Studio will give you lots of information.

Comment: Additionally you could search MSDN if it's a standard .NET type.

Answer (score 2):

1 - It is declaring "adapters" as an array of the type "NetworkInterface"

In vb.net arrays are declared and indexed with (...) syntax, in c# it is [...], so an array of strings would be

```
dim stringArray as string()
```

the same in c# would look like

```
string[] stringArray;
```

2 - This will be a range variable for the for each loop, to reference objects in the array, so it is not an array itself

3 - The foreach is saying "Loop through Adapter array, for each object found, assign the local variable Adapter the current value in the array, then run this block of code, repeat until we reach the end of the array"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, most of the time, you would see Step 2 and 3 in one line like this

```
For each adapter as NetworkInterface in adapters

Next
```

To answer your concerns: Step 1 is a collection of networkinterfaces, while number 2 is a local var of the object NetworkInterface. Step 3 makes you cycle through all NetworkInterfaces that are present in the collection from Step 1.